# Libgdx Terraria clone world takes too long to create

Tags: java, libgdx, chunks

I started working on a terraria clone in libgdx and got tile generation. Tiles are separated in 16x16 chunks, but spawning all the chunks takes way too long. Currently, i'm spawning 400 chunks(102400 tiles). Here's how i spawn the chunks:

```
data = new int[width][height];
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            data[x][y] = 1;
        }
    }
    chunks = new Chunk[chunks_x][chunks_y];
    for(int y = 0; y < chunks_y; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < chunks_x; x++){
            chunks[x][y] = new Chunk(x, y, this);
        }
    }
```

Tile spawning code inside of Chunk class:

```
tiles = new Block[World.chunkSize][World.chunkSize];
    for(int vy = 0; vy < World.chunkSize; vy++){
        for(int vx = 0; vx < World.chunkSize; vx++){
            if(world.GetTile(vx + x * World.chunkSize, vy + y * World.chunkSize) >= 1)
                tiles[vx][vy] = new Block(vx * 16 + x * World.chunkSize * 16, vy * 16 + y * World.chunkSize * 16, world.data[x * World.chunkSize + vx][y * World.chunkSize + vy]);
        }
    }
```

Generating a world of that size takes about 2+ minutes. I know that's a big number, but I'm curious as to how terraria (or any other clone) manages to make that time smaller. Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the block class(http://pastebin.com/SFCkJKur) and the entity class(http://pastebin.com/w3ay2nkb).

Comment: You sure about 102400 tiles? I have generated much larger maps with over a million tiles for testing purpose, they would load in a couple of seconds. I guess you do 16x16x400 so that would be 102400. Can't see anything strange in the code you currently posted, how big are these tiles in bytes? Can you show the full tile class? If you are storing things like texture data in it then that would be a bottleneck.

Comment: You are creating 102400 textures on memory, when you try to render that opengl will go nuts loading and reloading the same textures, just use a [wrapped texture](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Textures,-textureregion-and-spritebatch) using an [asset manager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) and make your entity just use a TextureRegion for rendering, im also creating a fallout_shelter/terraria/dwarf fortress clone, got a million tiles loaded in [less than a second](https://qls.pw/C0P), doing culling for rendering with a stable 60 fps on a pc without GPU..

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of the `Chunk` and `Block` classes? Are they for rendering? Because when you think about it, you don't *need* to do that. You really only need to render the tiles that are visible to the player at the current moment, and nothing more.

What many games of this nature do is determine the current location of the player and then calculate exactly what tiles/chunks need to be rendered and where.

Here are two good sources to get you started in that matter:

- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83253/is-there-any-way-to-load-pieces-of-a-tile-map-as-and-when-needed-and-not-the-en
- [Java Tile Based Game Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046401/java-tile-based-game-performance)

---

On the other hand, are the `Chunk` and `Block` classes just for containing the data that make up the world? In that case you don't need to initialize them either. You should store your data in a more lightweight manner - perhaps in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You motioned libgdx in your question, this engine comes with a well made Map API that handle Tile maps and provides other useful feature :

regarding to Libgdx official WIKI :

> Performance considerations
>
> While we try to make the renderers as fast as possible, there are a
>   few things you can consider to boost rendering performance.
>
> Only use tiles from a single tile set in a layer. This will reduce
>   texture binding. Mark tiles that do not need blending as opaque. At
>   the moment you can only do this programmatically, we will provide ways
>   to do it in the editor or automatically. Do not go overboard with the
>   number of layers.

take a look **[here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps)** for further info